Two associations to product entity in custom entity
I have created a custom entity "accessories".
In this entity I created a OneToOne association to the product entity.
I created a second association a ManyToOneAssociation to the product entity.
 public function getEntityName(): string
{
    return 'accessories';
}

protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection
{
    return new FieldCollection(
        [
            (new IdField('id', 'id'))->addFlags(new Required(), new PrimaryKey()), 
            new OneToOneAssociationField(
                'accessorie', 
                'accessorie_id', 
                'id', 
                \Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductDefinition::class, 
                false
            ), 
            (new FkField('accessorie_id', 'accessorieId', \Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductDefinition::class))->addFlags(new Required()),
            new ReferenceVersionField(\Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductDefinition::class, "product_version_id"),
            
            new FkField('compatible_id', 'compatibleId', \Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductDefinition::class),
            new ManyToOneAssociationField('compatibleproducts', 'compatible_id', \Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductDefinition::class, 'id'),
            new ReferenceVersionField(\Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductDefinition::class, "product_version_compatibleproducts_id"),


        ]
    );
}

The productExtension
 public function getDefinitionClass(): string
{
    return ProductDefinition::class;
}
public function extendFields(FieldCollection $collection): void
{
    $collection->add(
        new OneToOneAssociationField(
            'accessories', 
            'id', 
            'accessorie_id', 
            \ErgoflixProductExtension\Extension\Content\Product\Accessories\AccessoriesDefinition::class
        )
    );
    $collection->add(
        new OneToManyAssociationField(
            'compatibleproducts', 
            \ErgoflixProductExtension\Extension\Content\Product\Accessories\AccessoriesDefinition::class,
            'compatible_id'
        )
    );
}

When i try to save the first association in admin there is no problem.
        updateAccesorieValue(value){
          if (!this.product.extensions.accessories) {
            this.$set(this.product.extensions, 'accessories', this.repositoryFactory.create('accessories').create());
          }
          this.$set(this.product.extensions.accessories, 'accessorieId', this.product.id);
          this.isAccessorie = true
        }

My problem is to save the second association:
When i save the association throught "this.product.extensions.accessories.compatibleId" then Im able to save one right product id.
But since the "compatibleproducts" association is a ManyToOne I need to use a EntiyCollection. So i try to save multiple Products throught the collection:
I get the id of the product throught the userinterface. I search for the product and add the product to the collection.
 value.forEach(element => {
            let criteria = new Criteria()
            criteria.setIds([element])
            this.productRepository.search(criteria, Shopware.Context.api).then(productData =>{
                this.product.extensions.compatibleproducts.add(productData.last())
            })
        });

When I save the product in admin, the wrong id will get saved in the database.
I add the right id to the collection but the id that will be saved is the id of the product that i edit in the admin and not the id of the product that i add to the collection.

Which Shopware 6 version are you using?

Oh forgot it.. 6.6.6.1
